# Purely nondeterministic weakly stationary processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I found a necessary and sufficient condition for a stochastic process being purely nondeterministic in [Ihara (1993)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810209851). As follows:

A weakly stationary process $X$ is purely non-deterministic if and only if the spectral distribution function is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and its spectral density function $S_{xx}(\nu)$ satisfies
$$\left|\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\log(S_{xx}(\nu))d\nu\right|<\infty.$$

Kolmogorov proved it [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwj5iPm6-YXGAhXBjHIKHW7NAM4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fus%2Fbook%2F9789027727978&ei=zZt4VbnuJcGZygPumoPwDA&usg=AFQjCNE-P371RjL5xMhM1PwJ_g8OZE_9YQ&sig2=OcH8lST305vo6Sr6VEp7Rg&bvm=bv.95277229,d.bGQ), but I have troubles understanding the section of the work related to operator calculus. I was wondering whether somebody can guide me to a simpler prove of the above property?